# How to check for overlapping information in table view on kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, tableview

I am using the tableview from "https://github.com/ingenuity-ph/android-tableview-kotlin/blob/master/README.md" that is for a table that has fixed column header and row header and in which you can scroll both vertical and horizontal

The thing is that after I have passed over 10 columns information star to overlapping on the columns when I scroll in a horizontal way. information that is supposed to be on column A shows in column B or other.

When I debug it, the list of items passed to the table constructor has the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a known issue that the recyclerviews don't get resized correctly when they recycle.

https://github.com/ingenuity-ph/android-tableview-kotlin/issues/6

or

In original library https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/issues/202